# Checking if isset and is true?

Tags: php

Is there a function to check both

`if (isset($var) && $var)` ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The [`empty()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) will do the job.

Use it with the not operator (`!`) to test "if not empty", i.e.

```
if(!empty($var)){

}
```

Comment: `empty` will trigger a PHP warning if the variable is not set. `isset` does not trigger a warning.

Comment: @Kevin Peno No, it will not. From the documentation: `empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set.`

Comment: @Kevin peno i disagree on the warning generated. Check that out > http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#82942

Comment: I stand corrected. However I have a hard time believing it has always been like that.

Comment: this works without generating a warning. But i dunno if i can utilize it since `!empty` isn't that clear imo

Comment: The not operator is often used. Add a comment if you want to remember why you are using the not operator. ;)

Comment: `empty()` won't trigger any errors *unless you're testing an inexisting array key*.

Comment: It also doesn't consider 0 as a string either when part of a query string. I sees it as false.

Comment: it works, but to find out why the empty() was used quite difficult in  a project. It is good hack for you, but I prefer to use isset($var) && $var instead... more readable.

Comment: `empty()` is not triggering any error even for inexisting array keys or object properties. I also had hard time to believe it.

Comment: Where is this claim coming from that it supposedly triggers warnings for unset (I guess that what way mean by "unindexed") array keys? Was it ever true? Did that change with some php version? Because it really does not and probably never did.

Answer (score 20):

You may use the ?? operator as such:

```
if($var ?? false){
   ...
}
```

What this does is checks if `$var` is set and keep it's value. If not, the expression evaluates as the second parameter, in this case `false` but could be use in other ways like:

```
// $a is not set
$b = 16;

echo $a ?? 2; // outputs 2
echo $a ?? $b ?? 7; // outputs 16
```

More info here:
https://lornajane.net/posts/2015/new-in-php-7-null-coalesce-operator

Answer (score 7):

there you go. that should do it.

```
if (isset($var) && $var)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (! empty($var))
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though @phihag and @steveo225 are correct.

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
> considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals `FALSE`.
> `empty()` does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.
>
> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means
> `empty()` is essentially the concise equivalent to `!isset($var) || $var`
> `== false`.

So, it seems `!empty($var)` would be the equivalent to `isset() && $var == true`.

https://www.php.net/empty

Answer (score 1):

Try the `empty` function:
https://www.php.net/empty

Answer (score 0):

```
isset($a{0})
```

isset AND len is not 0 seems more reliable to me, if you run the following:

```
<?php
$a=$_REQUEST['a'];

if (isset($a{0})) { // Returns "It's 0!!" when test.php?a=0
//if (!empty($a)) { // Returns "It's empty!!" when test.php?a=0
    echo 'It\'s '.$a;
} else { echo 'It\'s empty'; }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = new stdClass;

$a->var_false = false;
$a->var_true = true;

if ($a->notSetVar ?? false) {
    echo 'not_set';
}

if ($a->var_true ?? false) {
    echo 'var_true';
}

if ($a->var_false ?? false) {
    echo 'var_false';
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
if (($var ?? false) == true) {
  
}
```

Comment: Looks redundant to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44523978/, just more verbose.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32902631)

Answer (score 0):

Well, "is true" and "equal to `true`" are two different things.
If you want to check "if `$var` isset and has "non-empty" value", do this:

```
if(!empty($var)){} 
//OR
if(isset($var) && $var){} 
//OR
if($var ?? false){}
```

While if you want to check (if `$var` isset and has a value of `true`), do this.

```
if(isset($var) && $var === true){}
//OR
if(($var ?? false) === true){}
```

Explanation.

- Three equal signs (`===`) mean that the value and data type in a valuable is the same. eg `1 == true;` will return `true`, but `1 === true` will return `false`.
- The `??` stands for isset and is not null.
- Any value that's is not `[], 0, null, '', false` will return true if checked as a condition in an if statement.

Answer (score -1):

I am amazed at all these answers. The correct answer is simply 'no, there is no single function for this'.
empty() tests for unset or false. So when you use !empty(), you test for NOT UNSET (set) and NOT FALSE. However, 'not false' is not the same as true. For example, the string 'carrots' is not false:

`$var = 'carrots'; if (!empty($var)){print 1;} //prints 1`

in fact your current solution also has this type problem

`$var = 'carrots'; if (isset($var) && $var){print 1;} //prints 1`

as does even this

`$var = '1.03'; if (isset($var) && $var == true){print 1;} //prints 1`

in fact... if you want to do as you described exactly, you need:

`$var = 'carrots'; if (isset($var) && $var === true){print 1;} //Note the 3 Equals //doesn't print 1`

I suppose the shortest valid way to test this case is :

`if (@$var === true){ print 1;}`

But suppressing errors for something like this is pretty awful practice.

Comment: Stackoverflow is telling me i have to explain why i downvoted you, so here i go. You wrote this answer making a point that the OP is confusing the value `true` with the concept of "truthy", yet you continued that mistake, because you claim `empty()` tests for "not false", when in fact it will treat a zero (even a string) the same as a `false`. So the apparently important distinction you wanted to clear up, is still present in your answer (in addition to also being unnecessary, since OP, by his example code, obviously just wanted to test for truthy). Also your 4th "prints 1" claim is incorrect.

Comment: @DigitalNinja points taken after a re-read. Although I don't think i'm incorrect given that 0 or '0' equate to false, and the point was not to cover all possible bases for type comparisons or go into that.. but to simply allude to why my answer (which is really just 'no') was correct. Regardless, code tweaked - cheers.

Comment: Both the question, the accepted answer, and your answer have some underlining implications (and the accepted answer is 100% true - if you know you're working with booleans). So i think your answer shouldn't be phrased in a "i'm amazed at these wrong answers" tone, but rather a "just to clear things up" tone. Because you seem to be attacking answers which do in fact work, just, depending on the environment. So you're not wrong, just more edge-casey, and in my opinion unnecessarily aggressive. No hard feelings, it's just that your answer might not be a required distinction.

Comment: I don't know how you read amazement as aggressive. I was pointing out my surprise that something i consider to be important and not 'edge-casey' consideration was overlooked. We can agree to disagree on the value of this answer. Regardless, its here now, and may be of some use to someone... so i'll leave it.

Answer (score -2):

Don't know if an exact one already exists, but you could easily write a custom function to handle this.

```
function isset_and_true($var) {
    return (isset($var) && $var == true) ? true : false;
}

if (isset_and_true($a)) {
    print "It's set!";
}
```

Comment: You realise the " == true" bit in "&& $var == true" is completely un-necessary? (Unless of course you meant to check for type equivalence with "&& $var === true".)

Comment: `((boolean)$x) ? true : false` is a tautology

Comment: this would raise a warning when passing $a if it's not set

Answer (score -2):

Check if the variable is set, and true. Ignore warning message

```
if(@!empty($foo))
```